# Replace file in s3 python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

If we have to completely replace an `existing file` in specified s3 folder path with another file `(with different filename)` using python (lambda)

At any instant of time the particular folder path in s3 would have only one file, which would be completely replaced with another when running the python code

Which boto function could be used for the above. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "replace file with a different filename"? If it has a different filename, then it is a different file, so what do you mean by "replace"? Are you wanting to simply delete an existing file when uploading a new file?

Comment: In that case, you would use `delete_object()` and `upload_file()`.

Comment: What you describe is _not_ updating a file. A file is 'updated' if a file is uploaded **with the same name**. What you are describing is the upload of a _totally different_ file (because it has a different name), so nothing is being 'updated'. It's like asking for a Ford car to be 'updated' into a Toyota car, when the transaction really involves selling one car and buying another.

Answer (score 4):

To do this you'd simply need to call the [upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) function which actually is a wrapper for the [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) function.

The function call would look like the below.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'replace/this/file.txt')
```

As long as you do not have object versioning enabled it will replace the previous object that existed for that key before.

.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Chris Williams, the object versioning is not enabled, however a simple upload_file doesn't seem to replace previous object when the new filename to be uploaded is different.

Comment: Are you 100% the key is the same? And does it work for new objects?